# How to use Google Service Account json file in .NET 6

Tags: .net-6.0, google-speech-to-text-api, google-cloud-api-gateway

I'm trying to create a .NET 6 web app that connects to Google Cloud API's, and host my app on Azure

I've created a service account with "Owner" permission, downloaded the json file, and placed the json file in the root of my directory.

How can I instruct my app to use this when connecting to Google Cloud API?

I see that I can set a windows environment variable, but I want to do it in my solution since it will be uploaded to Azure cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I instruct my app to use this when connecting to Google Cloud
> API?

Refer to this code for example: [Authenticating with a service account key file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/bigquery/api/Snippets/AuthenticateServiceAccount.cs?utm_source=cloud.google.com&utm_medium=referral)

BigQuery Client Example:

```
var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath);
var client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId, credentials);
```

Note from GCP [Authentication documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc):

> Creating a service account key is a security risk that should be
> avoided if possible. If you must create a service account key, make
> sure you keep it secure. Anyone with access to the key can gain all of
> the access that's granted to the associated service account.

The recommended solution is [Workload Identity Federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation)

Check this page for configuring Workload Identity Federation to [access GCP resources from Azure](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation#azure)

Comment: Thanks Rathish, much appreciated ... wishing you a great day :)